# TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given) error is specific to any python version?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I'm getting this error

> TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

using this code on python2.7.11:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

Bar()
```

The workaround to make it work would be:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bar, self).__init__()

Bar()
```

It seems the syntax is specific to python 3. So, what's the best way to provide compatible code between 2.x and 3.x and avoiding this error happening?

Comment: That syntax is for Python 3.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I see, thanks. To make my question a little bit more useful then I've edited a little bit asking some extra stuff

Comment: The Python 2 syntax is still valid in Python 3 in this case; if you want to support both versions, use that. Note however that there are lots of other incompatibilities between the versions.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Alright, tyvm. All clear then :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Yes, the 0-argument syntax is specific to Python 3, see [*What's New in Python 3.0*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins) and [PEP 3135 -- *New Super*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/).

In Python 2 and code that must be cross-version compatible, just stick to passing in the class object and instance explicitly.

Yes, there are "backports" available that make a no-argument version of `super()` work in Python 2 (like the `future` library) but these require a number of hacks that include a [full scan of the class hierarchy](https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/blob/master/src/future/builtins/newsuper.py) to find a matching function object. This is both fragile and slow, and simply not worth the "convenience".

Answer (score 27):

This is because of version of python. Check your python version with [python --version] it might be 2.7

```
In 2.7 use this [ super(baseclass, self).__init__() ]
```

---

```
class Bird(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Bird")

    def whatIsThis(self):
        print("This is bird which can not swim")

class Animal(Bird):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bird,self).__init__()
        print("Animal")

    def whatIsThis(self):
        print("THis is animal which can swim")

a1 = Animal()
a1.whatIsThis()
```

---

```
> In 3.0 or more use this [ super().__init__()]
```

---

```
class Bird(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Bird")

    def whatIsThis(self):
        print("This is bird which can not swim")

class Animal(Bird):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Animal")

    def whatIsThis(self):
        print("THis is animal which can swim")

a1 = Animal()
a1.whatIsThis()
```

Comment: Why would you make Bird a subclass of animal in an otherwise reasonable answer?

Comment: @MarkBolster How is that unreasonable?

Comment: @SolomonUcko - I think he meant why make Animal a subclass of Bird instead of making Bird a subclass of Animal... The latter is more logical.

Comment: @all this is just dummy example. But still I appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [future](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/future) library to have a Python2/Python3 compatibility.

The [super](http://python-future.org/reference.html?highlight=super) function is back-ported.

Comment: Oh boy, but that implementation.  Stack frame inspection and a full traverse of the namespaces of the MRO to find the context? I can't recommend actually using this.

Comment: Just use `super(ClassName, self)` and repeat yourself a little.

Answer (score 0):

Your default `python --version` is probably python2, you need to switch to python3 to use this syntax, to do so paste the following command in your terminal.

`sudo update-alternatives --config python`

If you get the error "no alternatives for python" then set up an alternative yourself with the following command:

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10`

then check your python version with

`python --version`

if you get a version 3.+ then your problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

for python 3.6
super(Bird,self).**init**() not working
super(Animal,self).**init**() worked for me.