# back compatible call to super() for python2/3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, inheritance, super

I have some code with I need to run in Python 2 and 3.
I have a class

```
class myClass:
  def __init__(self):
```

with a child. I have tried:

```
  from myClassfile import myClass as myBaseClass
  class myClass(myBaseClass):
          def __init__(self):
              super().__init__()
```

But it failed due known python2/3 differences.
I have followed [TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given) error is specific to any python version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963018/typeerror-super-takes-at-least-1-argument-0-given-error-is-specific-to-any)

until:

```
from myClassfile import myClass as myBaseClass
class myClass(myBaseClass):

  def __init__(self):
      super(myClass,self).__init__()
```

but this still fails due to:

```
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2, a class must inherit from `object` in order to be a [new-style-class](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/):

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
```

In Python 3, that may or may not be done - it does not make a difference.

Since in your code `myClass` inherits from `myBaseClass`, you should make sure that `myBaseClass` inherits from object:

```
class myBaseClass(object):
    ...

class myClass(myBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myClass, self).__init__()
```