# Code incompatibility issues - Python 2.x/ Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, constructor, super, python-2.6

I have this code:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Instruction (object):
   __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

   def __init__(self, identifier_byte):
      #type: (int) ->
      self.identifier_byte = identifier_byte

   @abstractmethod
   def process (self):
      print ("Identifier byte: ()".format(self.identifier_byte)) 

class LDAInstruction (Instruction): 
   def process (self):
       super(Instruction,self).process()
```

with works fine with Python 3.2 but not with 2.6. Then based on this topic: [TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given) error is specific to any python version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963018/typeerror-super-takes-at-least-1-argument-0-given-error-is-specific-to-any)

I changed the last line to:

```
super(Instruction,self).process()
```

which causes this error message on this precise line:

> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'process'

For me it seems that there is a "process" method for the super invocation. Is Python saying that "super" is an independent object, unrelated to instruction? If yes, how can I tell it that super shall only invoke the base class constructor?

If not, how I shall proceed? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: What does the `class` statement look like for `Instruction` (or whatever class is at the root of its inheritance tree)? Is it a new-style class that inherits from `object`? If not, `super` will not work for any classes in that hierarchy. The fix is pretty simple, just change it to be a new-style class, and it will work. New style classes were introduced with Python 2.2 in 2001, there's absolutely no reason to be using old-style classes in 2019. (I'd also suggest that Python 2.6 is unsupported and obsolete, but that's not immediately relevant to your issue.)

Comment: @khelwood what is the difference to what I was doing?

Comment: @Blckknght I edit my question and putted there the full source for the related classes. Anyway as far as I know I am using new style class.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the wrong class to `super` in your call. You need to pass the class you're making the call from, not the base class. Change it to this and it should work:

```
super(LDAInstruction, self).process()
```

It's unrelated to your main error, but I'd further note that the base-class implementation of `process` probably has an error with its attempt at string formatting. You probably want `{0}` instead of `()` in the format string. In Python 2.7 and later, you could omit the `0`, and just use `{}`, but for Python 2.6 you have to be explicit.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the error messages. But I did not understand the format stuff. Where shall the 0 go. What I know is that the expected output is not happening, all I am receiving is the "Identifier byte: ()" without anything else

Comment: Parentheses are the wrong characters to use for `str.format` in all Python versions. In Python 3 or Python 2.7, you can just put `{}` where you currently have `()` inside the format string. In Python 2.6, it won't number the brackets implicitly for you, so you need to explicitly put `{0}` instead of only `{}`. The whole line should be: `print("Identifier byte: {0}".format(self.identifier_byte))`