# Why do I get this error when I use super in a class python

Tags: python

When I try to create an instance of an object from a class that inherits from other class I keep getting this error

`TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`

If I don't create any instances then it runs. Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963018/typeerror-super-takes-at-least-1-argument-0-given-error-is-specific-to-any) question where it suggested to check python version. From what I see in the terminal I have Python 3.8.1 . Even when I try just copy and use a code from [this](https://realpython.com/python-super/) guide, it doesn't work and I get the same answer.

Here's the code:

```
class Developer(Employee):
    raise_amount = 1.10

    def __init__(self,first,last,pay,prog_lang):
        super().__init__(first,last,pay)
        self.prog_lang = prog_lang


emp_1 = Developer('Corey','Schafer',50000,'S')
```

But if I use

```
Employee.__init__(self,first,last,pay)
```

instead of `super()` it does work.

Comment: are you (still) using python 2?

Comment: try `super(Developer,self).__init__()`

Comment: for python 3 and above follow this ruling: `super().__init__()` instead of passing in the child class and an instance into `super()`

Comment: @hiroprotagonist no. installed 3.8.1.  Tried `super(Developer,self).__init__()` but it doesn't work as well. Same for just using `super().__init__()`

Comment: Are you sure you are *executing* this with python 3? Can you please show the entire traceback?

Comment: are sure that you are really running this python interpreter? what if you put `import sys; print(sys.version)` at the beginning of your code?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist well you are correct `2.7.16 (default, Dec  3 2019, 07:02:07) ` ... So why when I type in the terminal `python --version` it returns 3.8.1 ?

Comment: that depends on your operating system and your setup. and how you start the python script you are writing (e.g. on linux: does your file start with sth like `#!/usr/bin/env python3`)? this may be worth a fresh question...

Comment: I just use sublime text. I tried doing alias `python. = python3` but it doesn't seem to help. I'll try to look for more solutions and if not i'll post new question.