# AttributeError: 'MininetRouter' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, networking, mininet

Looks like the problem has to do more with Python rather than Mininet.

I am trying to build the customer network topology using mininet, but stuck here.

When I run the below code, I am getting below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CustomTopo_Router2.py", line 37, in <module>
    customTopo = NetworkTopo()
  File "CustomTopo_Router2.py", line 28, in __init__
    r1_obj = MininetRouter('122.1.1.1')
  File "CustomTopo_Router2.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.cmd('sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1')
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 353, in cmd
AttributeError: 'MininetRouter' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I dont even have any attribute `name` in `MininetRouter` class.

```
7 class MininetRouter ( Node ):
8
9     def __init__( self , loo_addr):    
10
11         #Enable IP forwarding on the ROuter
12         self.cmd('sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1')
13
14         # Create Loopback Interface and Assign Loopback Address to the Router
15         # All loopback addresses have mask 32
16         loo_config = 'ifconfig lo:1 ' + loo_addr + ' netmask 255.255.255.255 up'
17         self.cmd(loo_config)
18
19
20 class NetworkTopo( Topo ):
21
22     def __init__( self ):
23
24         # Initialize topology
25         Topo.__init__( self )
26
27         # Create a Router Object
28         r1_obj = MininetRouter('122.1.1.1')
29
30         # Add Router object to the topology
31         r1 = self.addNode('r1', r1_obj)
32
33
34
35 if __name__ == '__main__':
36
37     customTopo = NetworkTopo()
38
39     #Get handle to net to manage your topology
40     net = Mininet(topo=customTopo)
41
42     #start/deploy the Topology
43     net.start()
44
45     #Get Halt at Mininet CLI prompt
46     CLI(net)
47
48     #Destroy and stop the topology
49     net.stop()
50
51     # program ends here
```

What wrong am i doing here ? I have cross-chcked indentation.
PS : I am writing python code after couple of yrs now.

Comment: `MininetRouter` inherits from `Node` and in your `__init__` you call `self.cmd`. I assume that method is inherited from `Node`. The thing is, you never called `Node`'s `__init__`. My guess is that the class instance has not been setup properly. You should do `super().__init__()` (adding any needed parameters) before calling any inherited methods.

Comment: Also, `Topo.__init__( self )` should be `super().__init__()`.

Comment: @tdelaney added `super(Topo, self).__init__( )` & `super(Node, self).__init__( )`  lines as first line in the constructor of both classes. Yet same error. I am running python 2.7.6.

Comment: This thread mentions the syntax of using super in python 2.7.x
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963018/typeerror-super-takes-at-least-1-argument-0-given-error-is-specific-to-any

Answer (score 0):

I made some modifications to the code, in order to make it work and more in line with the Mininet API. This should work, for what you are trying to do.
Be careful that I didn't put a controller because I don't have it installed, but you can use the Openflow Controller, RemoteController, etc.
I hope this can be useful to you.

```
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Node
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mininet.cli import CLI

class MininetRouterModified( Node ):
    "A Node with IP forwarding enabled."

    def config( self, loo_addr, **params ):
        super( MininetRouterModified, self).config( **params )
        # Enable forwarding on the router
        # Create Loopback Interface and Assign Loopback Address to the Router
        # All loopback addresses have mask 32
        loo_config = 'ifconfig lo:1 ' + loo_addr + ' netmask 255.255.255.255 up'
        self.cmd(loo_config)
        self.cmd( 'sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1' )

    def terminate( self ):
        self.cmd( 'sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=0' )
        super( MininetRouterModified, self ).terminate()

class NetworkTopo( Topo ):

    def build(self, **_opts):

        # Create a Router Object
        #r1_obj = MininetRouter('122.1.1.1', name="r1")
        # Add Router object to the topology
        r1 = self.addNode(name='r1',loo_addr='122.1.1.1', cls=MininetRouterModified)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    customTopo = NetworkTopo()

    #Get handle to net to manage your topology
    net = Mininet(topo=customTopo, controller=None)

    #start/deploy the Topology
    net.start()

    #Get Halt at Mininet CLI prompt
    CLI(net)

    #Destroy and stop the topology
    net.stop()
```